# Android grab activity content view and register touchInterceptor

Tags: android, popupwindow, ontouchlistener

Given an activity, how can I grab dynamically register a Touch Interceptor to its parent view?

I have a popupwindow and when I click on certain areas of the screen I would like the activity's view (anchor view) to handle the click even rather than the popupwindow.  the popupwindow class has a method to register a new touch interceptor.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setTouchInterceptor(android.view.View.OnTouchListener) .  This touch interceptor class either absorbs the click event or passes the click event to the window's children.  Obviously, the activity's view is not the popupwindows child, from what I understand it is the other way around.

This line of code `activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)` will grab the activty's content view (in fact this is what I anchor the popupwindow to using showAtLocation()), but how do i register a touch interceptor to it?

Comment: you register it to a View.OnTouchListener not to a View

Comment: Well, to be more clear, I registered the popupwindow to the activity's view, and I am looking for a way to dynamically register a `View.OnTouchListener` to that very same view I anchored the popupwindow to (i.e., the underlying activity's view)

Comment: honestly its not more clear, at least not for me

Comment: Okay, well, more simple put: How do you dynamically register a TouchInterceptor to an Activity (or its parent view) given the activity's instance.

Comment: you set a TouchInterceptor to a OnTouchListener, not to an Activity nor a View, let your Activity implement OnTouchListener and just pass "this" in setTouchInterceptor

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway of implementing the interface at runtime? I suppose not.

Comment: what iface? OnTouchListener?